# Django: issue with a simple form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm new at django and I'm having problems with a simple form POST.I have a ModelForm in forms.py and when user enters information in html, views.py taks it and saves it. However, I keep getting an error saying it can't find the view doesn't exist in view.py. Please help me find the error. Thank you!

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       (r'^mypage/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'recipeapp.views.my_view'),
```

forms.py

```
class NewRecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    user_info = forms.ForeignKey(User)
    title = forms.CharField(min_length=2,max_length=50,required=True,)
    post_date = forms.DateField(auto_now=True)
    ingredients = forms.TextField(widget=forms.Textarea(),)
    picture = forms.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d',)
    content = forms.TextField(widget=forms.Textarea(),)
```

views.py

```
@csrf_protect
from recipeapp.forms import NewRecipeForm

    def my_view(request,username):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = NewRecipeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        else:
            form = NewRecipeForm()

        return render_to_response('postlogin.html',{'username':username},{'form': form}, RequestContext(request))
```

postlogin.html

```
        <form action="" method="post" id="form">
            {% csrf_token %}

                <div id="dish-name">
                <label><p>Dish name</p></label>
                {{form.title}}
                </div>

                <div id="ingredients">
                <label><p>Ingredients</p></label>
                {{form.ingredients}}
                </div>

                <div id="content">
                <label><p>Content</p></label>
                {{form.content}}
                </div>

                {{form.picture}}
       </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that really your whole views.py? You have at least three issues:

Firstly, you haven't imported `csrf_protect` - like any name, a decorator needs to be defined before you can use it.

Secondly, you have to decorate an actual function, not a file. The decorator should go just before the function definition for `my_view`.

Thirdly, your indentation is broken - the `def` should not be indented at all.

Given all those, I expect that Python is failing to import your views because of syntax errors.

Also note that you shouldn't really use `csrf_protect` - you should enable CSRF protection in your middleware (it's on by default) and only use the `csrf_exempt` decorator, and then only on very very rare occasions.